# Copay wallet transaction history unavailable?

Tags: copay

Ever since updating my Copay wallet to the newest version to resolve the vulnerability issue, it won’t show my transaction history. Recent transactions will show on the main screen for about 30 minutes, but if I try to open them up to view the details I get an error message. This is especially frustrating since I should have a little more BTC sitting in my wallet than I actually do, but I can’t see where the funds may have gone since the transaction history won’t load. All it shows is an error message saying “Could not update transaction history”. Help?
Using iPhone 6, iOS 11.4.1, copay for iOS v5.4.0
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top search result on Google says

> **Refresh the transaction cache**
>
> Select your wallet > Tap on the icon in the upper right corner of the screen > Choose "Transaction History" > Choose "Clear Cache" to reset your transaction list.
>   Note: Your wallet will say 'Updating Wallet' until the list has been retrieved.
>
> **Refresh the server's cache.**
>
> Select your wallet > Tap on the icon in the upper right corner of the screen > Go to "Wallet Addresses" > Choose Scan addresses for funds
>   Note: Your wallet will say 'Scanning Funds' until the addresses have been scanned.
>
> Please do not uninstall the app or delete the wallet if you did not back it up properly, in such case, please do so. The wallet backup is the only way to recover your wallet.

Maybe that helps?

Comment: I guess I should have googled it - clearing the transaction history cache worked instantly! Thank you!!